# Mock instance method in python unittest using mock

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I'm trying to mock an instance method of an object contained in another object.

I got two objects

```
class CreditCard(object):
    def charge(self, amount):
        if amount < 0:
            raise Exception('Invalid amount')
        print "charging %d" % amount

class Transaction(object):
    def __init__(self, credit_card, amount):
        self.amount = amount
        self.credit_card = credit_card
        self.status = 'PRISTINE'

    def pay(self):
        self.credit_card.charge(self.amount)
        self.status = 'COMPLETE'
```

This is a simplified example of what i'm trying to acheive

```
class TestTransaction(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        cc = CreditCard()
        t = Transaction(cc, 10)

    def test_should_not_mark_transaction_as_complete_if_charge_failed(self):
        with mock.patch('t.credit_card.charge') as mock_charge:
            mock_charge.side_effect = Exception
            with self.assertRaises(Exception):
                t.pay()
            self.assertEquaL(t.status, 'PRISTINE')
```

There is a lot of logic inside `charge` so I'm trying to isolate the transaction test by mocking the charge.

Thanks, python 2.7

Answer (score 2):

Since you are mocking method of a class, you can patch it directly:

```
import mock
import unittest

from your_code import CreditCard, Transaction

class TestTransaction(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.cc = CreditCard()
        self.t = Transaction(self.cc, 10)

    @mock.patch('your_code.CreditCard.charge', side_effect=Exception)
    def test_should_not_mark_transaction_as_complete_if_charge_failed(self, mock_charge):
        with self.assertRaises(Exception):
            self.t.pay()
        self.assertEqual(self.t.status, 'PRISTINE')
```

Be sure to udpate the module path in the patch, where are defined your classes.

Also, I corrected your initial example, due to several errors (use of global variables instead of instance attributes in the test case).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are passing a `CreditCard` instance into `Transaction`, just create a [Mock object](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock) and pass that instead.

```
class TestTransaction(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
         self.fake_cc = Mock()
         # set up any side effects, return values etc. of the fake cc
         # in your tests as needed...
         self.t = Transaction(self.fake_cc, 10)

    def test_should_not_mark_transaction_as_complete_if_charge_failed(self):
        self.fake_cc.side_effect = Exception
        with self.assertRaises(Exception):
            self.t.pay()
```

Comment: Thanks, i've tried that. I'm getting a ValueErrror if i dont pass `CreditCard` as spec, e.g `Mock(spec=CreditCard)`, but even like that i'm getting a `AttributeError: Mock object has no attribute '_state'`. `CreditCard` is a related sjango model of transaction. I wonder if it's even possible.

Comment: Well, it should be possible. If you are seeing `AttributeErrors`, make sure that the mock mimics the real `CreditCard` instance well. There might also be other things that the `pay()` method depends on, try mocking these as well (what you want in general is to isolate the method under tests from its dependencies and test it in isolation).

Comment: Basically determine with a debugger where the code when under test fails due to the mock passed in and adjust the mock accordingly.

Comment: The mock credit card object looks good. I get the error when i assign it to the parent model (I dont get that error when assigning an actual cridt card object). I think i'll just try and mock the method of the existing credit card instead.

Comment: This is perfectly fine, too, because you have a direct control over the `CreditCard` instance that the `Transaction` instance uses.